# getting div inner text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I have this html code

```
<td style="width: 123px;" class="x-grid3-hd x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-CORE_USERS_ALIAS">
    <div style="" class="x-grid3-hd-inner x-grid3-hd-CORE_USERS_ALIAS" title="Text">
        <a href="#" class="x-grid3-hd-btn"></a>Text<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-grid3-sort-icon">
    </div>
</td>
```

I'm trying to get the 'Opportunity Owner Alias' text in jquery and have tried with this code:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
console.log('a: '+j$('a.x-grid3-hd-btn').next().text());
console.log('div: '+j$('div.x-grid3-hd-inner').text());
```

but I get a blank text. 
I have also seen that this part of code

```
<a class="x-grid3-hd-btn" href="#"></a>
Text
<img class="x-grid3-sort-icon" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
```

is grey in firebug. What does that mean? I see that text rendered in html so it must be somewhere... thanks.

Comment: Because `.next()` targets your `<img/>` tag!

Comment: what about j$('div.x-grid3-hd-inner').text()?

Comment: You need to `trim()` it [see](http://jsfiddle.net/k6wPb/) !

Comment: check this outhttp://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/x3JSP/

Comment: What about this :<a href="#" class="x-grid3-hd-btn">Text</a> or <a href="#" class="x-grid3-hd-btn"></a><span>Text</span>

Comment: none of this works, i dont understand why

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors:

The first is a typo in you html:

Change this:

```
<a href="#" class="x-grid3-hd-btn"></a>Text<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-grid3-sort-icon">
```

For this:

```
<a href="#" class="x-grid3-hd-btn">Text</a><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-grid3-sort-icon"/>
```

The text is inside a. Close the tag img.

And use this selector: `$(".x-grid3-hd-btn").text()`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('a.x-grid3-hd-btn').parent().text()
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".x-grid3-hd-inner").text();

or

$('a.x-grid3-hd-btn').parent().text();